# Function not reacting after onClick event on mobile device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, openid-connect

I have a React component called Button.
In this component I have a property called onClick, this propert fires the onClick event of the HTML button element.
When I pass an alert() function to this onClick property it works on both desktop and mobile.
When I pass an OIDC.UserManager.signinRedirect() function to the onClick property it works on desktop but not on mobile.

This is what I have:

```
const {userManager} = useContext(ActiveUserContext);

return (
  <>
    <Button text="Login" onClick={() => userManager!.signinRedirect()} /> //Not working on mobile device
    <Button text="Login" onClick={() => alert("Login")} /> //Works on mobile device
  </>
);
```

Is it maybe the `!` after `userManager`?
Does anyone have an idea why `signinRedirect()` does not redirect on a mobile device?

Comment: typo: `!userManager.signinRedirect()`?

Comment: i have never used oidc, but for a check in two ways, remove the exclamatory  or put exclamatory infront of userManager and try it. and try some another function like handClick a custom function . and put a console.log('hitting here'). if the custom function works in mobile then we can check for oidc related issue to mobile specifically since it works in desktop

Comment: @JosephD. It's no typo ;)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I think has to something with the `!`

Comment: So i think we are figuring out the pblm so close, did you put a console log, and check whats comming in desktop and whats in mobile. so from there may be we will be able to understand, may be in mobile it can be undefined, then nothing wont happen isn't

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS it's not possible that userManager is undefined on mobile if it isn't on desktop right?

Comment: @MrLine do we need any extra configuration for mobile, i am just guessing it. because if we think in all ways may be we will be able to found out the soln

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS there are no extra configurations needed. It should work on mobile as it does on desktop

Comment: @MrLine I also need to search on this so basically onClick of the button what it does, what is this oidc

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I found out what the problem was. On desktop I used localhost, on mobile I used my machine IP. UserManager has some json settings which are different. I Thanks you for thinking with me!

Comment: @MrLine, shall i post that one as answer so the people who is comming they will be able resolve quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As further checking on the question, the issue was related to the running part. **The web application was running in localhost and mobile it was using machine ip. Since the UserManager has some json settings which are different caused the issue.** @MrLine